# Why a bash script is not working properly after being installed via .deb package in /usr/local/bin and without installation it works?

Tags: bash, package-management, scripts, debian-installer

I have developed a bash script named `njsearch` that should perform a search in a given folder, and save the log inside `auditlogs.log` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

logs_dir=/var/log/mylogfolder
mydata=/path/to/mydata
daysbefore=1

Find()
{
    truncate -s 0 $logs_dir/auditlogs.log
    echo "Searching files .$1"
    find $mydata/ -mtime -$daysbefore -name *.$1 >> $logs_dir/auditlogs.log
    cat $logs_dir/auditlogs.log
}

# Get the options
while getopts ":hmkaro:" option; do
    case $option in
        h) # Display Help
            Help
            exit;;
        m) # Find mp4
            Find mp4
            exit;;
        k) # Find mkv
            Find mkv
            exit;;
        a) # Find avi
            Find avi
            exit;;
        r) # Find rar
            Find rar
            exit;;
        o) # Enter new file format
            namedial=$OPTARG
            Find $namedial
            exit;;
        \?) # Invalid option
            echo "Error: that's not a valid option"
            exit;;
    esac
done
```

This script works great, the problem comes when I generate the .deb installer file following the steps explained [here](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/build-binary-deb-package-practical-guide). Once installed, the script does not perform the searches.

I'm missing something here about creation and compilation this script for being part of Debian OS?

PS: I checked the `+x` permission for the script, and nothing

Any solution to this?

**UPDATE:** I recently found out that after installing it, if I do a logout - login, then this script works without any problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: You should double-quote `*.$1` to prevent it from potentially expanding to a list of matching files in the current directory. More generally, you should double-quote bash variable expansions like `$mydata` and `$log_dir` as well - see for example [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, but, is not any code trouble. This works perfectly, my problem is given in the post-installation of this code as part of a package.
I recently found out that after installing it, if I do a logout - login, then this script works without any problem.
Any ideas?